# Want to join another table with get_posts() wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to join another table with `get_posts()` method and fetch fields from new table.

I know about `add_filter( 'posts_where','calback_function_name')`.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no build in function/method to do so. you have to write custom sql query to accomplish this task

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use your own query if you are going to start joining tables.

This is quite simple to do, and you can use WordPress's methods to use it's database handler.

```
global $wpdb;

$query = '
  SELECT *
  FROM '. $wpdb->posts .' p
  JOIN my_custom_table c ON p.ID = c.ID  
';

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT );
```

There is lots of information on this in the [WPDB WordPress Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).